# Switching the axis of a plot

Tags: plotting, series-expansion

I have a plot but the x and y axis need to be switched.  The problem is that I can't explicitly solve for the other so I can change the axis.

```
e = .65;

Ec[M_] = M + 
  Sum[(1/2^(n - 1)*
      Sum[((-1)^k*(n - 2*k)^(n - 1))/((n - k)!*k!)*
        Sin[(n - 2*k)*M], {k, 0, Floor[n/2]}])*e^n, {n, 1, 3}]
Plot[Ec[M], {M, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2 \[Pi]}, {0, 2 \[Pi]}}]
```

Basically, I want Ec to be on the x axis and M the y axis.  As of right now, they are swapped.

Comment: You've seen `ParametricPlot[]`?

Comment: @J.M. I have used it before.

Comment: In that case, ponder on what `ParametricPlot[{Sin[y], y}, {y, 0, 3}]` does, and see if you can apply this to your problem at hand.

Comment: I was actually encouraging you to answer your own question using my hint... ;) Please do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per J.M.s suggestion, the solution to the problem is:

```
e = .65;

Ec[M_] = M + 
   Sum[(1/2^(n - 1)*
       Sum[((-1)^k*(n - 2*k)^(n - 1))/((n - k)!*k!)*
         Sin[(n - 2*k)*M], {k, 0, Floor[n/2]}])*e^n, {n, 1, 10}];
ParametricPlot[{Ec[M], M}, {M, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2 \[Pi]}, {0, 2 \[Pi]}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotStyle -> Red]
```

Comment: Excellent. ${}$

Comment: @MichaelE2 not for another day.

Comment: OK - just wanted to make sure you knew.  Sorry to be a bother.